# Understand the group id in google cloud storage acl "GroupById"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In the acl file of the google cloud storage bucket, there are a few "GroupById" sections, how do we figure out which group they are really?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessControlList>
    <Entries>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="GroupById">
                <ID>00b4903a9723223d04b0b0f62a685816f6507795e4fd99efef36a2f1e6de00d7</ID>
            </Scope>
            <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="GroupById">
                <ID>00b4903a9790857bbc0cdcd793997d3cc14342d54187d1d541989da7e514fac2</ID>
            </Scope>
            <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
        </Entry>
        <Entry>
            <Scope type="GroupById">
                <ID>00b4903a9765a87209b3e1452e437e7454c3af51863bdeff32e647151c238bda</ID>
            </Scope>
            <Permission>READ</Permission>
        </Entry>
    </Entries>
</AccessControlList>
```

I know one of them is probably an app engine. But I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These groups represents Project Team Members, Project Editors and Project Owners. By default these groups has the following permissions.

- Project Team Members

  READ
- Project Editors

  FULL_CONTROL
- Project Owners

  FULL_CONTROL

You can find these IDs along with the respective groups in Google APIs Console ([here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect)). Select your project and click on Google Cloud Storage item in the left-side menu. Then in Google Cloud Storage IDs section, you can see these IDs.